# Search function exits after 2nd call

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple search function - `addFormulaTestDataLoop` - that gets called multiple times to return a row number.

In the first two calls (call 1 and call 2), it finds the beginning and ending rows for the first block. Then I call it two more times (call 3 and call 4) to get the next beginning and ending row numbers. ***But*** on the third call (call 3), rather than returning the value, it goes to `End Function`. However, when I step through the code, the search routine `gFindInColumn` has the correct line number in it.

```
Public Function gFindInColumn(search As Variant, columnNum As Double, Optional rowNum As Double) As Double

If rowNum = 0 Then
    rowNum = 2
End If
gFindInColumn = Columns(columnNum).Find(What:=search, _
                                After:=Cells(rowNum, columnNum), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                SearchFormat:=False).row
'MsgBox "value = " & gFindInColumn, vbExclamation, "Finished"
End Function
```

This function is called like so:

```
dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.Show
temp = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaseLineEndTemp.Value
sStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineStartDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineStartTime.Value
eStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineEndDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineEndTime.Value

sRow(1, 1) = gFindInColumn(sStr, 3)
eRow(1, 1) = gFindInColumn(eStr, 3)
Call addFormulaTestDataLoop(temp, sRow(1, 1), eRow(1, 1))

'Dur
temp = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaseLineEndTemp.Value
sStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineStartDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineStartTime.Value
eStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineEndtDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineEndTime.Value
qtyDur = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtDurQty.Value

sRow(2, 2) = gFindInColumn(sStr, 3)
eRow(2, 2) = gFindInColumn(eStr, 3)
Range("A" & sRow(2, 2)).Value = "DURING"
Call addFormulaTestDataLoop(temp, sRow(2, 2), eRow(2, 2))
```

It fails at `sRow(2, 2) = gFindInColumn(sStr, 3)`, but works on the first two calls?

Comment: Are you switching workbooks/worksheets in there somewhere (maybe in `addFormulaTestDataLoop`)? Your `gFindInColumn` function references `Columns` which looks at the ActiveSheet of the ActiveWorkbook and will blow up on you if you switch to a different worksheet. Maybe pass in the worksheet you're searching in, just to be sure you're searching on the right one.

Comment: No, not switching because when I step through the code it does come up with the correct value. But good point, I'll pass in the worksheets and make it explicit

Comment: You also have an unqualified reference to `Cells()` in your `After:=` parameter. May want to clean that up, too.

Comment: Not an expert in VB but how would a qualify it, by adding an active sheet?

Comment: I did add wsData.Activate just before i called gFindInColumn but that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to find only matches which occur after a specific row number: in that case you need to make sure that Find() hasn't loop back around...

```
Public Function gFindInColumn(search As Variant, rngCol As Range, _
                              Optional rowNum As Long = 2) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = rngCol.Find(What:=search, After:=rngCol.Cells(rowNum), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'only return non-zero if the found cell is *after* rowNum
        gFindInColumn = IIf(f.Row > rowNum, f.Row, 0)
    Else
        gFindInColumn = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Also switched out your "search column" to a Range object so there's no ambiguity about which sheet the Find runs on.

Note also you can handle default values for optional parameters directly in the parameters list.

Comment: That looks great but, maybe I'm not understanding the range I've called with sRow(1, 1) = gFindInColumn(sStr, "C3:C" & lRow) but it doesn't even step into the function. Thanks for all the help so far with my OJT on VBA ;-)

Comment: `gFindInColumn(sStr, Range("C3:C" & lRow))`